# Can ios app can only store card to vault?

Tags: paypal

I want to use Paypal's rest Api's for card storage and using that card. There are 2 cases that need to be handled.

First is,
In my IOS app i want to store user's credit card to the paypal vault (don't want to charge and delete it). App should not be able to delete and charge the card.

Second is,
On server side I would doing all the processing related to payment as background task (deletion of card from vault is also included).
Basically I will provide some endpoint for storing the card token returned by paypal to database. So ios app can post data to that endpoint.

Is there a way handle this?

Currently I am using access token method on server side (bearer token). But I cannot give that token through endpoint because of security issuse.
And ios app cannot use paypal's access token method because that token has the ability to charge and delete the card.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for the link.